# wso2am 1.6.0 error while updating WSDL endpoint in Publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have wso2am 1.6.0 installed on Centos 6.3 running under IBM JDK 1.7. After adding a new WSDL Endpoint API via Publisher I get an error when trying to update the newly added API.

```
2014-01-14 08:52:39,421 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-49] ERROR APIProviderHostObject Error while updating the API- accountInfo-1.0.0
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while updating the API :accountInfo
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:666)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:496)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag:6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5.call(/publisher/modules/api/update.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_9(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:35)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:116)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
Caused by:
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:666)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:579)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:425)
        ... 63 more
Caused by:
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to reset the WSDL : /registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--accountInfo1.0.0.wsdl
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:787)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:541)
        ... 64 more
Caused by:
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException:  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:767)
        ... 65 more
Caused by:
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at '/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--accountInfo1.0.0.wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--accountInfo1.0.0.wsdl
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2259)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:84)
        ... 66 more
Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/admin--accountInfo1.0.0.wsdl
        at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:173)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2238)
        ... 69 more
2014-01-14 08:52:39,433 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-49] ERROR add:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while updating the API- accountInfo-1.0.0
```

I found this JIRA item https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1841 which shows a similar issue but it is supposed to be fixed in version 1.6.0. Any ideas on whether this is a issue or is my setup incorrect. He

Comment: Is your WSDL protected by Basic Auth?

Comment: No it isn't. Quite simply any time I go to edit a publisher SOAP endpoint the publisher application errors because it can't find the wsdl in the location it expects.